# Can I pre-populate jQuery auto complete field with values selected from another jQuery autocomplete field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, auto-populate

I am using jQuery UI's auto complete in my form. I have two sections of the form one shows up after submitting the first one, I need to pre populate another auto complete field in the second section with the values of the first one.

I had to make the second one as auto complete since I will be cloning it if
user wants to add another row of that info and need to give them options.

Can this be done ?

Comment: $("#autoComplete2").val($("#autoComplete1").val()) ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The short answer is Yes, you can. If you want a more clear answer or suggestion, you will want to include an example of your current code or what you have tried. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using the select function in  autocomplete

```
   $(#idofElement1).autocomplete({
     source: xsource,
     autofocus: false,
     delay: 10,
     minLength: 3,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $(#idofelement2).val(ui.item.label);
        false;
    }
});
```